# Eclipse EPIC Plug-in and auto-completion/content assist on passed complex objects?

Tags: perl, autocomplete, epic

SO community,

Is there a best practice coding standard on how to consistently get the auto-completion / content assist working on methods of a Perl Module when passed into a method. For example:

```
sub main {
   my $moduleObject = MyNameSpace::ModuleObject->new();
   processModuleObject($moduleObject);
}

sub processModuleObject {
  my $moduleObject = shift;
  $moduleObject->...    <- that is were I want context assist/auto-completion to work

}
```

The best work around to get it work was the following which I am not happy with:

```
sub main {
   my $moduleObject = MyNameSpace::ModuleObject->new();
   processModuleObject($moduleObject);
}

sub processModuleObject {

  my $moduleObject = MyNameSpace::ModuleObject->new();
  $moduleObject = shift;
  $moduleObject->runLogic();

}
```

Are there any coding best practices we should be aware of?

/Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass anything to the processModuleObject Method. There are no strongly typed arguments and method signatures in Perl, or at least no mechanisms to enforce it.

How can the EPIC IDE be possibly be able to figure out what type the method's arguments are? I don't know.

Still, you can use Moose and the optional Add-on-Module MooseX::Declare, so you could write

```
method processModuleObject (MyNameSpace::ModuleObject $myobj) { ... }
```

but EPIC won't recognize the Moose syntax and method declarations. So you would loose the Eclipse "outline view". But you would get some verbose runtime errors at most, pointing you to type mismatch errors where parameters were passed.

IMHO, it would be cool if someone extended EPIC this way, making it "Moose-aware".